# Interfacing with the despotify gateway

Tags: python, despotify

I'm using despotify, a CLI spotify client, in a little project of mine. One way of interfacing with despotify is with the gateway (http://despotify.se/clients/). I can start the gateway and it will listen at localhost at port 8080, but I have no idea how to pass commands and arguments. You can't do something like "127.0.0.1:8080/login?username=user&password=pass", as it returns an error. Has anyone else worked with despotify?

Answer (score 0):

if you launch despotify from your CLI, it should show you this message:

```
Usage: ./despotify <username> <password>
```

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LUySm2Z8Yk) shows you a basic introduction, it's the best place to start from

Answer (score 0):

Just netcat or telnet to your gateway and use the commands:

```
nc localhost 8080
login user password
200 0 OK Login successful
search someartist
```